# Erro ao validar pagina inicial após fazer Login/Senha

Tags: mvc, asp.net-core

Eu tenho uma validação de acesso (Login/Senha) que caso for verdadeira, deveria retornar para página inicial, porém me retornar o seguinte erro:

> InvalidOperationException: RenderBody invocation in '/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml' is invalid. RenderBody can only be called from a layout page.

Segue Controller que faz a verificação e deveria retornar para view:

```
if (cli.ValidarAcesso(cli.CliCodigo, cli.CliSenhaWeb, _config) > 0)
            {

                return View("_Layout", new Clientes());
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse erro não é do Controller, é da sua View. Tente colocar `@RenderBody()` no "centro" da sua view. Se não funcionar, posta o código da sua view aqui.